# Smalltalk usage of printFormat: method

Tags: smalltalk, visualworks, gnu-smalltalk

Can someone please give me an example of how to use the printFormat: method in Smalltalk to format a string?

Eg:

'123456789'  printFormat: aFormat should return something like $123,456,789.00

Comment: As far as I can tell `printFormat:` is implemented only in _Date_. Do you have something special on your mind or you just want a method to print number in a special way?

Comment: I wanted to print it in currency format. 
I just found that it can be done like this:
aNumber printFormat: $#,###.00
However there exists a floating point round off error with above implementation for 123456.123123

Comment: So you can either submit a bug report or fix it :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a number to a string in Smalltalk (visual works)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19104125/how-to-convert-a-number-to-a-string-in-smalltalk-visual-works)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to find examples of the usage of a method in smalltalk is to select it and then search for senders. Most smalltalks (VW, Squeak, Pharo, Dolphin, Amber etc) have a keyboard shortcut for that.

If the number is too large, you might want to take a look at implementors.

Smalltalk often has little help text and comments, but a lot of real code using a specific construct.

We try to avoid using [floats in currency calculations](http://forum.world.st/Inconsistencies-in-NumberPrintPolicy-td4652934.html). ScaledDecimals work better, and you might want to create a real Money class

Answer (score 0):

[VIsualWorks]
Pls, see at Class NumberPrintPolicy. This class has nice comments.
In your case solution may be following:

```
(NumberPrintPolicy defaultInstance)
    thousandsSeparator: $,;
    decimalPoint: $..
NumberPrintPolicy print: 123456789 using: '$#,###.00'
```

I changed thousandsSeparator and decimalPoint because I have default russian locale at VisualWorks with another values of thousandsSeparator and decimalPoint.